# Laravel make every object become an array

Tags: php, laravel

I got an query and it return object. I want to make each of the object become an array:

Here is my query:

```
$transactions['transactions'] = Transaction::groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
      ->selectRaw('FLOOR(SUM(amount)) as total, DATE(created_at) as date')
      ->orderBy('created_at')
      ->get()->toArray;
```

Here is the result I get:

```
"transactions": [
  {
    "total": "88781",
    "date": "2015-01-01"
  },
  {
    "total": "95630",
    "date": "2015-01-02"
  },
  {
    "total": "57857",
    "date": "2015-01-03"
  },
  {
    "total": "85252",
    "date": "2015-01-04"
  },
  {
    "total": "64763",
    "date": "2015-01-05"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```
 "transactions": [
  [
    "88781",
    "2015-01-01"
  ],
  [
    "95630",
    "2015-01-02"
  ],
  [
    "57857",
    "2015-01-03"
  ],
  [
    "85252",
    "2015-01-04"
  ],
  [
    "64763",
    "2015-01-05"
  ]
]
```

I've tried to `json_decode` but got no luck.

Any solution?

Comment: How are you getting your result? Are you printing your result into an html/blade template? Are your dying and dumping your variable to get that result? etc

Comment: How does `::->` work? Typo I'm guessing?

Comment: @PatrickStephan No. I tried to using nvd3 chart and it expecting array instead of object.

Comment: @MarkDavidson sorry messing with 'enter' when edit the code. Updated without typo :)

Comment: The Expected result doesn't make sense since you have an array of associative objects. You'd have to drop the  keys ("total", "date").

Comment: @Rainner yes dropping the key is no problem as long the total, and date is in correct order. I'll edit my expected result. sorry about that

Comment: By default Laravel returns every model in PHP's StdClass, you can access it's properties by `$object->property1`. You can also use foreach on object and process as array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try mapping over the values in the collection and converting them to non-associative arrays:

```
$transactions_result = Transaction::groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
      ->selectRaw('FLOOR(SUM(amount)) as total, DATE(created_at) as date')
      ->orderBy('created_at')
      ->get();

$transactions_result_as_array = $transactions_result->map(function($item, $key){
    return [$item->total, $item->date];
});

$transactions['transactions'] = $transactions_result_as_array->toArray();
```